# PHP file rendering output as text why..?

Tags: php, html

I have two PHP files, both of them are contact forms. One file has HTML 4 doctype and the other has HTLM 5 doctype.

When I open the first file it renders properly i.e. completely loads web page with full colors, graphics etc. but when I render the second file it just displays the HTML code in the browser in the text format.

the content of the first file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Discover Brazil</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Myriad_Pro_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Myriad_Pro_600.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#comp').focus();
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
</head>
<body id="page1">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sent'])){
// Contact subject
$comp=  $_POST['comp'];
$ur_name = $_POST['ur_name'];
$position = $_POST['position']; 
$add = $_POST['add'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$pin =$_POST['pin'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$tel =$_POST['tel'];
$Cell =$_POST['cell'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$pro = $_POST['pro'];
$busi= $_POST['busi'];
$target = $_POST['target'];

// Details
$message="Name of the Company :- " . trim($_POST['comp']) .
   "\n\nName :- ". trim($_POST['ur_name']) .
   "\n\nPosition :- ". trim($_POST['position']) .
   "\n\nAddress :- ". stripslashes(trim($_POST['add'])) .
   "\n\nCity :- ". trim($_POST['city']) .
   "\n\nPin Code :- ". trim($_POST['pin']) .
   "\n\nState :- ". trim($_POST['state']) .
   "\n\nTelephone No :- ". trim($_POST['tel']) .
   "\n\nCell No :- ". trim($_POST['cell']) .
   "\n\nFax No :- ". trim($_POST['fax']) .
   "\n\nEmail ID :- ". trim($_POST['email']) .
   "\n\nWebsite :- ". trim($_POST['website']) .
   "\n\nCompany Profile :- ". trim($_POST['pro']) .
   "\n\nBusiness With Brazil for Last 3 years :- ". trim($_POST['busi']) .
   "\n\nTarget for Brazil for 2014 :- ". trim($_POST['target']);

$to = "email@domain.com";
$subject = "This is subject";
$header = "From:$email \r\n";
$sendmail = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
}
?>
<!-- header -->
```

THe content of second file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sl</title>
<meta name="description" content="Place your description here">
<meta name="keywords" content="put, your, keyword, here">
<meta name="author" content="Templates.com - website templates provider">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/maxheight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_300.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.faded.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqtransform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#faded").faded({
speed: 200,
crossfade: true,
autoplay: 3000,
autopagination:false
});
$('#domain-form').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
});
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://info.template-    help.com/files/ie6_warning/ie6_script_other.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-size: 16px}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body id="page1" onLoad="new ElementMaxHeight();">
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sent'])){
 // Contact subject
$author=  $_POST['author'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$details = stripslashes($_POST['details']);

// Details
$message="Name :- " . trim($_POST['name']) .
   "\n\nEmail :- ". trim($_POST['email']) .
   "\n\nSubject :- ". trim($_POST['subject']) .
   "\n\nMessage :- ". stripslashes(trim($_POST['details']));

$to = "email@domain.com";
$subject = "This is subject";
$header = "From:$email \r\n";
$sendmail = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
}
?>
<div class="tail-top">
```

Comment: how are you opening the files?

Comment: What is your code like? We cannot help you without an example...

Comment: via links. the files are linked

Comment: can u please share the little code of those files?

Comment: @OctoD : Normal HTML with some php scripts.

Comment: can you post few first lines of both htmls?

Comment: If your page has external css, pls check its path...

Comment: @SmartGirl maybe you could you modify your question with the html headers and the php code. It could be a wrong path to an external css.

Comment: what is the filename (and more specifically, the **extension**) of the second file?

Comment: Do you have a demo? What mime type is returned in the Chrome networking panel for each file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the extension of the second file is a recognized document extension.
So if its, `secondFile.txt` or `secondFile.php.bk` , rename it to `secondFile.php`

**edit**: just a small guess, but have you tried closing the body and html tags with:

```
</body>
</html>
```

at the bottom?

Comment: @SmartGirl what is the url to the second script?

Comment: Can you also please copy paste what you see in the browser when visiting the second file? I'm curious to know if it shows from `<html>` through `</html>`. And if it also shows the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem definition is not very clear, your question/description could also describe several different problems.. So chances am naming potential causes that you already are aware of, but for completeness sake:

First of all, to see a HTML file as a rendered HTML page, you need to open it in a browser. This works local (from your own disk/computer) and from websites (via `http` connection)

Second, to have PHP code actually run you need to have some computer execute it before sending it to you. This usually happens on the computer that accepted your http connection, if it recognizes and can execute your `*.PHP` file.

Then there are things that can also complicate stuff, like the `content-type` in the header that PHP can alter before returning a webpage.

**Update:** Thanks for attaching source.
The reason a browser sometimes displays text instead of html, is related to the content-type. Mostly this can be derived by file extention, the doctype or other html properties.
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
It could help to add this to your 2nd file, or it may be even better to properly fix the file so that the browser can correctly guess that its html to begin with. (unroot the problem at its cause)

Comment: Thanks i saw you already attached source by the time i posted my answer. I updated my answer.

Comment: I saw your html5 code, it's not complete. there is no echo, no html except few tags. You can view source to know what is output. It's incomplete code. May be this is reason.